# How can I get the facebook user-agent string when click a link in Facebook app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, url, user-agent

I have created a facebook application that is used for posting a message to the wall. The application works fine. In the message I post there is a link. When I use the iphone facebook app and click this link instead of having Safari open immediately, the url opens in an internal frame of the facebook app and by click the small arrow it has the on the right bottom I can choose 'Open in safari'. This happenes only in iphone.

Is there a way to make my links open directly yo Safari?
Or is there a way yo get at least the facebook user-agent string so as to have a special treatment for this case?

Thanks in advance